# How to create a self join association excluding parent record using Hibernate and JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

**Consider the following JPA entity**

## Employee.java

```
/**
 * An employee.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable
{
  @Column(name = "id")
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  // Peers are all employees having same title, except this employee.
  // Note: This attribute is temporary made transient to avoid
  // 'org.hibernate.MappingException'
  // What annotation should I put here to make it a `many to many` association.
  private transient Set<Employee> peers;

  @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
  private String title;

  // Omitted Getters and Setters.
}
```

A sample project is also available [here](https://github.com/aman-in-java/Jpa-example).
I want to have all peers for an employee, that is, all other employees having same *Title* except the current employee.

I am looking for the equivalent of the following SQL: `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE title = ? and id <> ?`. I have tried various variations of @ManyToMany, but all of them throw errors.

Note: I want to do this from the entity class only (Without Query).

**Consider the following example:**

Let us suppose an organization has following employees with their corresponding titles:

Associate : John, Tim, Peter

Manager   : Donald, Robin, Robert

When someone query for `John's` peer then only `Tim and Peter` should be fetched, Similarly for `Tim's` peer `John and Peter`.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has two powerful options to declare filtering conditions using annotations: `@Where` and `@Filter`, see the official docs [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filtering). I suppose `@Filter` can help in your usecase since you need the `title` as parameter at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Frifle,
I have tried this, but in order to implement the filter I have to enable that filter, according to the documentation by default filters are disabled, Since I strictly want to do it within the `Employee` class, I want to load `peers` by using `getPeers` method only.